# Can I make mount.cifs reconnect against the same DNS name?

Tags: linux, mount

I run Linux in a VM on a Windows host.  When I'm in the office, my Windows host machine self registers it's DNS name and it's `mymachine.myco.com`.  When I'm at home, it self registers as `mymachine.local`.  In the Linux guest, I want to mount shares on `mymachine`.  I do that in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//mymachine/development /home/ben/Development     cifs    credentials=/home/ben/.creds/alderaan,rw,user,noauto,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777    0 0
```

This works in the office and at home if I type `mount Development`.  However, once it's mounted, I can't then switch locations and have it still work.  It appears that once mount has run it's tied to the IP address not the DNS name and if that changes it no longer works.  Is there a way I can make it reconnect on timeout so that it switches over if the IP address changes?

Or at the very least is there a way so that I can easily unmount the directory?  At the moment I just get `mount point busy` if I try to remount it and I can't even type `ls` on my home folder since it times out getting the attributes of the mount point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, the answer appears to be to do a lazy unmount of all cifs mounts:

```
sudo umount -a -t cifs -l
```

And then remount them all:

```
sudo mount -a -t cifs
```